# Minus 1 or another value from a split.length? (Java)

Tags: java, split, string-length

How would you minus from a split.length method? Would you need to assign it to an int like the code below or would you have to store the split.length value. An example I want to minus 1 from the split.length value.

```
 String[] split  = i.split( " " );

 int a = split.length;      
 //Split method separates Char from spaces

 a -= 1;

 System.out.println("[ " + a + "]" + " Spaces in " + '"' + i + '"' );
```

Comment: What do you really want to achieve here? Reduce the length of the array?

Comment: What are you *actually trying to achieve*? Changing the value of `a` doesn't change the array. If you need a new array that just doesn't have the last value, create a new array and copy the other elements in...

Comment: say for example the value of the array is 3 I would like to minus 1 from that.

Comment: Also, the length of the array is the actual number of times the string was split.  If you're trying to print out the "amount" of matching items, it's `length` and not `length-1`.

Comment: @Sridhar Yes :)

Comment: @markspace yes but I wanted to know how would you, say if you wanted to minus 1 from that?

Comment: Well you did that, then printed `length` instead of `a`.  Got to print the right thing.  (If you're asking how to change `length` itself, you can't.  Arrays in Java are a fixed size and you can't change that.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorten array length once element is remove in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777762/shorten-array-length-once-element-is-remove-in-java)

Comment: @EverythingIsScience I;ve added an answer for you.

Comment: Sorry I did that but it still doesn't work. So, in theory, this should work, then it may be a bug in somewhere in the program. @markspace

Comment: Yeah if you did that, please show the code and we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I belive what you wanted was to remove the last element from the array.

I would do it like the following,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String i = "this is a test string";
        String[] split  = i.split(" ");

        System.out.println("Before" + split.length);

        split = Arrays.copyOf(split, split.length - 1);

        System.out.println("After" + split.length);
    }

}
```

Thanks to @markspace for pointing to use `Arrays.copyOf`

From your edit, I think you just want to print the no of spaces in string.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String i = "this is a test string";
        System.out.println("[" + (i.split(" ").length - 1) + "]" + " Spaces in \"" + i  + "\"");
    }

}
```

This should do it.

Comment: Argh!  No!  Use `Arrays.copy*`.

Comment: Hmmmm, good thank you but is there a way without using the .util and more simpler like this

Comment: @EverythingIsScience Just modified the code

Comment: Better but without no .util.Arrays

Comment: @EverythingIsScience added a manual way which uses no packages

Comment: Check new example edit @Sridhar more like that.

Comment: @EverythingIsScience You're using quotes wrongly. Check my new code sample

Comment: @EverythingIsScience Happy to help. But, next time ask the question more relevently :)

Comment: @Sridhar will do, I am new to this :) and thanks.